# Why prediction from randomforest classifier .predict() and .predict_proba() don't match?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I trained a simple randomforest classifier, then when I test the prediction with the same test input:

```
rf_clf.predict([[50,0,500,0,20,0,250000,1.5,110,0,0,2]])

rf_clf.predict_proba([[50,0,500,0,20,0,250000,1.5,110,0,0,2]])
```

The first line returns `array([1.])`, whereas the second line returns `array([[0.14, 0.86]])` where the prediction is the first float `0.14` right?

How come those two don't match? I'm a bit confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predict()` function returns the class to which the feature belongs to and `predict_proba()` function returns the probability of the feature belonging to the diffrent output classes.

Example:
Output of `predict()` function gives you the result that the feature belongs to class 1 (i.e) array([1.])

Output of `predict_proba()` function gives you the probabilities of the feature belonging to each output class array([[0.14, 0.86]]). 14% probability of feature belonging to class 0 and 86% probability of feature belonging to class 1.

Refer Docs: [`predict()` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict), [`predict_proba()` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to return the prediction class by using both of them, I have a `dict` defined for example `0-not dead/1-dead`, for `predict()`, how can I return the corresponding class?

Comment: `dict[clf.predict()[0]]` will return you the prediction class.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) part of `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`, specifically the `predict_proba` method.

*Returns: ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes), or a list of n_outputs. such arrays if n_outputs > 1. The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute classes_.*

The output you're getting (array([[0.14, 0.86]])) is thus a list of the probabilities for each of the classes that are present in your sample, for each sample input. The method `predict()` simply predicts one class for each input (so that's why you're getting array([1.]) as return).